# Post date time field to MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Data to MySQL table ?

```
start = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
start_time = start.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
end_time = start.strftime('%YYYY-%mm-%dd %HH:%MM:%SS')
    time_dict={"start":start_time,"end":end_time}
    for x,y in time_dict.items():
         t =Schedular_logs(
            startTime=x,
            endTime=y)

         db.session.add(t)
         db.session.commit()
```

I am getting this error sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError)(1292, "Incorrect date time value: 'start' for column 'startTime' at row 1")

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the value 'start' in the column and this value is string. You should pass the value which is date time : Y-m-d H:i:s (change the code inside your for loop)